# Will assetBundle in Unity 5.4 be compatible with 5.6, vice versa?

Tags: unity-game-engine

If I build an assetBundle in Unity Editor 5.6, will it work in the game built with Unity 5.4?

What about vice versa?

Answer (score 2):

Based on this [post](https://forum.unity3d.com/threads/unity-5-is-streaming-asset-bundles-now-compatible-between-unity-versions.276448/) on the Unity forums, assetBundle from 5.0 on are forward compatible - no express guarantee on backward compatibility from what I can see.

Comment: That matches [this post](https://forum.unity3d.com/threads/unity-5-3-backward-compatibility-of-asset-bundles-created-in-5-x.374544/) saying that 5.3 can read 5.2, but not vice versa.

Comment: please note that there's no backwards compatibility (at least, not always). for example - 5.3.6 will not be able to use asset bundles built with 5.5.3. we've faced some issues with that.